# Remove a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove a file that physically exists on my system. I wrote the following function using Python 3 that does not work:

```
def remove_file(output_file):
    print("Removing the output file: ", output_file)
    try:
        os.remove(output_file)
    except RemoveFileError as e:
        remove_stat = e.returncode
    else:
        remove_stat = 1
    if remove_stat == 0:
        print("File removed!")
    else:
        print("File not removed.")
```

When I try to remove the file using the above code this is the result I get:

```
Removing the output file:  ../../../output_files/aws_instance_list/aws-master-list-03-21-2019.csv
File not removed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `remove_stat = 1` to `remove_stat = 0`.

Comment: remove `try` and `except` block to show the real error. only write `os.remove(output_file)` to see what is the real error

Comment: You're setting `remove_stat` to `1` in the `else`, which is executed when no exception is raised.

Comment: So you set `remove_state` to `1` upon success, but then you check that it's equal to `0` to see if it was successful? When would that condition ever happen?

Comment: You need to add a statement before removing the file. Probably a checking to see whether the file exists or not. Or maybe you are passing the wrong file location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` clause of your `try` statement is being executed when **no** error occurred. See [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Try this updated version of your code:

```
def remove_file(output_file):
    print("Removing the output file: ", output_file)
    try:
        os.remove(output_file)
    except RemoveFileError as e:
        remove_stat = e.returncode
    else:
        remove_stat = 0
    if remove_stat == 0:
        print("File removed!")
    else:
        print("File not removed.")
    print("File exists:", os.path.exists(output_file))
```